# I don't understand "The sum of capacities for all queues, at each level, must be equal to 100" In CapacityScheduler

Tags: hadoop

In http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html, I saw

> yarn.scheduler.capacity..capacity: Queue capacity in percentage (%) as a float (e.g. 12.5).
>   **The sum of capacities for all queues, at each level, must be equal to 100.** Applications in the queue may consume more resources than the queue's capacity if there are free resources, providing elasticity.

But, i don't understand the bolded sentence.
What's the *level* mean? If the sum of capacities for all queues isn't 100, what will happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queues can have sub-queues.  At the top level are all of the queues and the the sum of the capacities for those queues must be 100.  If a queue has sub-queues, that would entail a second level of queue and the capacities for the sub-queues for the queue need to add up to 100.  Every breakdown of a queue into sub queues is another level with the same "sum of 100" requirement.  If the sum for a level isn't 100 I suppose you'd get an error.

Comment: As you say,if there are 2 queues with Top level now,the first queue's capacity is 50 and the second is also.Then,I add the third queue now,i need to modify the first or second capacity and set the thrid capacity to make the three capacities can add up to 100?